# copy files from server share to C:\Temp and then run the batch file that is copied locally

Tags: command-line, batch, script, login

I need a login script to copy the contents of a directory from a file share to the local computer, and then run a bat file that gets copied locally as part of that process.

```
if not exist "C:\Temp\" mkdir C:\Temp
copy "\\server.domain.local\installer\*.*" "C:\Temp"
CD C:\Temp
call install.bat
```

Install.bat runs an msi with a mst.

Is that the best way to do this? (Will this work...)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You wish to install it on *every* login? What about user interface?

Comment: I need to install it one time, for every user. The install bat calls an installer that gets copied over and runs it silently.

Comment: Is this computer inside a domain, or a stand-alone computer?

Comment: about 70 users/computers in a domain.

Comment: The file copy works fine, but the install.bat file doesn't appear to be getting called.

Comment: @Paul Installers usually require admin-rights/elevation. The login-script (and everything started from there runs under the user that is logging in and even if that user had admin-rights it doesn't run elevated. And try "call c:\temp\install.bat" because it is not certain C: is actually the active drive.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` doesn't (or didn't) normally change drives. This may be why your `call` fails.

Try

```
C:
cd \Temp
```

Alternatively, try:

```
cd /D C:\Temp
```

Comment: This and/or the install requires admin-rights which the user doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism you describe risks to not work for the reasons described
in the comments : It will run on every login and the users might not
have the required permissions.

Since this is a domain, it's much more logical to use the domain tools
that are made exactly for this situation.

See the Microsoft article of
[Use Group Policy to remotely install software](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/use-group-policy-to-install-software).

This article describes how to distribute software as a one-time
operation by creating a distribution point on the publishing server.

If the installation method does not fit your need, see also the post
[Run a PowerShell script once on all computers as admin via GPO without changing execution policy](https://serverfault.com/questions/1102273/run-a-powershell-script-once-on-all-computers-as-admin-via-gpo-without-chan).

This article describes how to run once a PowerShell script on
all the computers in an Active Directory domain.